# How do I put two concurrent internships on my resume?

Tags: software-industry, resume, internship, research

So this summer, I had two independent and different internships. One was a full-time 9-5 paid "developer" internship. The other one was a remote internship at an academic institution. I somehow managed to pull it off and finished my projects at both the places (by working weekends, at night etc). My supervisors at both the places knew of the other internship and were comfortable with it hence I did not have a hassle.

Now I face a problem of putting them up on my resume. I am slightly apprehensive about putting both of them on my resume,as in my view it would make it seem like the internships were amateur ones and not a professional ones(please do correct me if you think this is not true). It was suggested to me by a mentor that I strike off the remote one, as it will not count towards my professional work experience, but I wish to retain it as it was some really good work and moreover was "research" based(in a field important to me and my career goals).

So my questions are:

1. Will showing two overlapping internships on my resume cause any problems? Will it be taken suspiciously as being forged/not authentic? (Forged internships on resumes are a chronic problem in my country)
2. Is there a way I can prevent such a confusion/suspicion? How should I explain this to any potential employers who have their doubts regarding the same?

PS. If it matters, this is in the field of computer science and I am a college senior who will soon start looking for full time opportunities.

Comment: List one under a job section and the other under an internship section.

Answer (score 4):

List both in separate listings. Pick the one that is most useful to the job you are applying and list it first. Add enough detail of what you did that is it clear you did something at these internships. In the cover letter, explain how you logistically did two internships at the same time and why you chose to do so.  Be prepared with recommendations from both for when you are called to an interview.

Comment: +1 for properly utilizing the cover letter to provide context around your resume

Answer (score 2):

> Will showing two overlapping internships on my resume cause any
>   problems? Will it be taken suspiciously as being forged/not authentic?
>   (Forged internships on resumes are a chronic problem in my country)

If forgeries are common, probably. At the same time, I don't think anyone would be stupid enough to intentionally try to fake two internships at once. You have more to gain by having two internships than to lose because some people will be suspicious. The good companies who are suspicious would follow up on their suspicions rather than dismissing you outright.

> Is there a way I can prevent such a confusion/suspicion? How should I
>   explain this to any potential employers who have their doubts
>   regarding the same?

The best way to alleviate suspicion is to include specific details that explain the confusing aspects. For example, to show that it's possible to work two jobs at once, mention that one job was part time on nights and weekends only. If the two jobs are located in different cities, specify that one was remote work only. If a position is unpaid, or if your projects were more of an independent study with little oversight, these also help show that one of the positions had much more flexibility to squeeze in your free time. You should expect questions in interviews about how you managed this too. Above all, just be honest and don't try to exaggerate things to make your case more desirable or believable.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can prevent such a confusion/suspicion? How should I explain this to any potential employers who have their doubts regarding the same?

There don't seem any way to avoid suspicion.Since you yourself are aware of the forgery of certificates.Your future employer must be seeing a number of forged cases.So you are supposed to explain the truth and with your experience considering multiple internships it don't seem hard.

> Will showing two overlapping internships on my resume cause any problems? Will it be taken suspiciously as being forged/not authentic? (Forged internships on resumes are a chronic problem in my country)

The difference between original and forged documents is that the original ones have a good backing behind them.As you have explained here it all seems legitimate.All you need is backing for everything you state in resume.Here all you have to tell is the truth how you managed to complete both.Considering the scenario of forged docs in your country.You have a hell better experience of your field which is enough to justify your internships.